# Org mode table column sort in evil mode?

Tags: sorting

You sort org mode tables using `C-c ^` in emacs, but how do you do the same in evil/vim mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two Options

1. Keep using <kbd>C-c ^</kbd>.  Just because you're in evil doesn't mean you lose access to the original bindings.
2. While in command mode, type <kbd>:org-sort RET</kbd>.  In evil, you can interactively call elisp functions as if they were faux vimscript functions.

As always, you're also free to bind the `org-sort` function to whatever keybindings you want.  There isn't any default evil binding for it that I know of.